# Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Transaction results in an account (1) with insufficient funds for rent

Tags: web3.js

I'm creating a transaction to send funds to two different addresses with `@solana/web3.js`.

Let's say that my balance is around 1 SOL
I want this transaction to send ALMOST all my funds, so

```
const transaction = new Transaction().add(
    SystemProgram.transfer({
      fromPubkey: new PublicKey(publicKey),
      toPubkey: new PublicKey("address1"),
      lamports: 1 SOL - 100.000 lamports
    })
  ).add(
    SystemProgram.transfer({
      fromPubkey: new PublicKey(publicKey),
      toPubkey: new PublicKey("address2"),
      lamports: 10.000 lamports
    })
  )
```

Doing this I should have enough funds to pay the fees and my balance should be around 90.000 lamports after the transaction.
Why does this transaction fails?

Answer (score 4):

Solana accounts require a minimum amount of SOL in order to exists on the blockchain, this is called [rent-exempt account](https://docs.solana.com/developing/intro/rent#rent-exempt).

Currently, on mainnet, this amount is around `1250000` lamports, which your `90.000 lamports` do not cover.

Comment: How can one get exaclty that amount needed to exist? Is there also a simple way to implement a mechanism that sends like ALL the funds in the address?

Comment: You can you this call, https://docs.solana.com/api/http#getminimumbalanceforrentexemption

Comment: Ok, now can i calculate the size in byte of my account?

Answer (score 1):

It this situation when you're trying to send a specific amount of lamports to two different addresses while retaining a certain balance. However, the issue here is how you're calculating the lamports to send. You should calculate and set the lamports based on the difference you want to retain, like this:

const balance = 1 SOL; // Assuming 1 SOL = 10^9 lamports
const amountToSend1 = balance - 100000; // Calculate the amount to send to address1
const amountToSend2 = 10000; // Amount to send to address2

const transaction = new Transaction().add(
SystemProgram.transfer({
fromPubkey: new PublicKey(publicKey),
toPubkey: new PublicKey("address1"),
lamports: amountToSend1
})
).add(
SystemProgram.transfer({
fromPubkey: new PublicKey(publicKey),
toPubkey: new PublicKey("address2"),
lamports: amountToSend2
})
)

Comment: Just started learning web3.js at Christex Foundation Sierra Leone. Thanks to C.oogo